# Three coplanar vectors - proving a statement

Tags: analytic-geometry, vectors

Is it true that three vectors $\vec{u}, \vec{v} , \vec{w} $ lie on the same plane if and only if there exists constants $A,B,C,D$ for which $A\vec{u} + B\vec{v} + C\vec{w} +D =\vec{0} $ ?

If so, how can I prove it ? I know that three vectors lie on the same plane if and only if $\vec{u}\cdot (\vec{v}\times \vec{w} ) =0 $ . Does it help ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You prove the statement by using either $A\mathbf{u}+B\mathbf{v}+C\mathbf{w}=0$ or your second statement. Proof of these equations is a different question entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two non collinear lines form a linearly independent basis that will span a plane, however introducing a third coplanar vector means the three vectors will be linearly dependent since the third can be written as a linear combination of the previous two. Therefore the definition of linearly dependence and coplanar are equivalent for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Therefore you need an $A,B,C$ not all zero such that 
$$A\mathbf{u}+B\mathbf{v}+C\mathbf{w}=0$$ as this is the common test for linear dependence.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is inconsistant: you are adding vectors and numbers.

The good condition is: $\vec u, \vec v$ and $\vec w$ are copolanar iff there exists three real numbers $A,B,C$, not all zero, such as : $A\vec u + B\vec v + C \vec w =0$.

In linear algebra, it is the definition of "three vectors are coplanar".